# Body message in PHP incomplete

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Hy. I have this code in PHP

```
$venue=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'venue');

$firstName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstName');
$lastName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastName');
$dateofBirth=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dateofBirth');
$gender=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gender');
$country=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$phone= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone');
$address=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'address');
$englishLevel=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'englishLevel');
$profession=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'profession');
$remarks=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'remarks');


$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'first_name');
$last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'last_name');
$dateof_birth=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dateof_birth');
$placeof_birth=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'placeof_birth');
$nationality=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nationality');
$passaport=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'passaport');
$dateofIssue=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dateofIssue');
$placeofIssue=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'placeofIssue');
$dateofExpiry=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dateofExpiry');
$residence_address=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'residence_address');
$occupation=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'occupation');
$addressOfEmployer=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'addressOfEmployer');

if(isset($_POST['venue'])){
        //$radio_input = $_POST['radio'];
        $data = "Venue & Date: " . $venue . "\n".
    "Name: " . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . "\n" .
    "Date of birth: " .$dateofBirth . "\n".
    "Gender: " .$gender . "\n".
    "Country: " . $country . "\n" .
    "Email: " . $email. "\n" .
    "Phone: " .$phone . "\n".
    "Address: " .$address . "\n" .
    "Level of English: " .$englishLevel . "\n" .
    "Occupation or profession: " .$profession . "\n" .
    "Other remarks or questions: " .$remarks . "\n";
} 
 if ( $_POST['yesno'] == 'yes') {
      $data =     "Name: " . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . "\n" .
       "Date of birth: " .$dateof_birth . "\n" .
       "Place of birth: "  .$placeof_birth . "\n" .
       "Nationality: " .$nationality . "\n" .
       "Passaport: " .$passaport . "\n" .
       "Date of issue: " .$dateofIssue . "\n" .
       "Place of issue: " .$placeofIssue . "\n" .
      "Date of expiry:" .$dateofExpiry . "\n" .
      "Residence address: " .$residence_address . "\n" .
      "Profession: " .$occupation . "\n" .
      "Address of employer: " .$addressOfEmployer . "\n" ;
 }
```

I have a condition that says: If you need visa, choose yes and another form appear and then you should complete all the fields
I received the mails but when I complete and the form for "VISA" I received only the fields from second form. What I've done wrong?

**UPDATE:** this is a part from H

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6 padding-top-10">
    <label for="englishLevel" class="control-label">Level of English(bad, medium, good, excellent):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="englishLevel" required data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" id="englishLevel" placeholder="your english level" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 padding-top-10">
    <label for="occupation" class="control-label">Occupation or profession:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profession" required data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" id="profession" placeholder="your profession" />
  </div>
</div>
<label for="remarks" class="control-label padding-top-10">Other remarks or questions:</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="remarks" id="remarks" placeholder="remarks or questions" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 padding-top-10">
  <label for="visa" class="control-label padding-top-10">Do you need a visa to come to course venue?</label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck" value="yes" /> YES
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck" value="no" checked="checked" /> NO
   </label>
   </div>
 <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
  <div class="col-sm-12 padding-top-10">
    <h1 span style="color:red">If you need visa, please complete the following data:</h1>
    <br>
    </div>
    <label for="firstName" class="control-label">Full name(as written in the passaport):</label>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-6 padding-top-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" id="first_name" placeholder="First" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 padding-top-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" id="last_name" placeholder="Last" />
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 padding-top-10">
      <label for="dateofBirth" class="control-label">Date of birth:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateof_birth" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-pattern="/^(\d{1,2})(\/|.)?(\d{1,2})(\/|.)?(\d{4})$/" placeholder="MM.DD.YYYY" data-date-format="MM.DD.YYYY" id="dateof_birth" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 padding-top-10">
      <label for="placeofBirth" class="control-label">Place of birth:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="placeof_birth" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" id="placeof_birth" placeholder="your place of birth" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 padding-top-10">
      <label for="nationality" class="control-label">Nationality:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nationality" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" id="nationality" placeholder="your nationality" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

The form is looking like that:
[image: form1]

[image: form2]

Comment: Is the second form appended to the first form or independent? You probably need to capture the data from the first form and then send it with the second form. I don't see your forms so not sure how you are building/processing.

Comment: It is in same form.

Comment: Maybe your html generates two form tags? Then half of the data won't be submitted to the server.

Comment: You are emailing `$data`? Looks like you overwrite that when `visa` is set.. or rather when `$_POST['yesno']` is `yes`.

Comment: you can var_dump($_POST); at the beginning of your php script to figure out what's going on, if data is not there, then it's an HTML problem, otherwise it's a PHP problem

Comment: I've updated with a part from HTML

Comment: Yes @chris85 I'm emailing $data. If someone need Visa then the body message must contain and the rest of the form, otherwise it must contain only the required fields.

Comment: So you need to append `$data` not overwrite it, use `$data .=`... or if that part of the form can be stand alone check first if `$data` is empty. If empty assign then, if not empty concatenate.

Comment: You're right @chris85. Thank you for your time